# unique record from purchasecost

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have the following data in `poitem` table.

```
poitem(po_num,line,item,item_cost)
```

Here is the data:

```
po_num       line   item        item_cost
--------------------------------------------
P000164703    1 1004600067  300.00000000
P000163933    2 1004600067  111.32000000
P000163933    3 1004600067  111.32000000
P000164700    1 1004600067  111.32000000
P000164720    2 1004600067  151.32000000
```

I want to retrieve all of the top 1 record details  for unique costs for item.

For instance:

```
 1) P000164703 1  300
 2) P000163933 2  111.32
 3) P000164720 2  151.32000000
```

Comment: We need more background on this question to help you solve your problem.

Comment: as shown in the above example each item has different po's with diffrerent cost's. i wan't to retreive the details of po,line,cost with unique item_cost per item.

Answer (score 1):

```
select po_num,line,item,item_cost
from
(
select *, rn=row_number() over (
    partition by item, item_cost order by po_num, line)
from poitem
) X
where rn=1
```

Comment: +1, but it should probably be `order by po_num, line` to ensure the expected result for the given sample data at least.